# Mutil monitor mouse tracking

Tags: mouse, mouseevent, tracking

I have a need to track mouse position.  While I have attempted several ways of doing this, I never am able to follow/capture the position if the mouse is on another monitor.

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool GetCursorPos(ref Point pt);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool GetCursorInfo(out CURSORINFO pci);

    public void GetPosition(out int X, out int Y)
    {
        Point pt = new Point(0, 0);
        X = Y = 0;

        if (MouseMonitor.GetCursorPos(ref pt))
        {
            X = pt.X;
            Y = pt.Y;
        }
```

This works but only on one screen.  I also read that I might try GetCursorInfo.  I have attempted this but it always comes back false.
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool GetCursorInfo(out CURSORINFO pci);

Any suggestions?  My goal is to track mouse position (outside of my own app) regardless of what screen it is on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample code works for me on my dual-monitor system...

You can actually simplify things quite a bit by using the .NET Framework:  the System.Windows.Forms.Cursor class has a static Position property.

For example, I created a new Windows Forms project and then dragged a System.Windows.Forms.Timer onto the form.  I set the Enabled property to true, and added this code to the Tick event:

```
this.Text = string.Format("{0}, {1}", Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
```

Ran the project and it worked as expected on both my monitors...

Comment: Did this code provide any improvement?  If not, can you provide more specific information on how the cursor tracking doesn't work on another monitor?

Answer (score 0):

Use DWORD GetMessagePos() - it gives you the last windows message mouse position. But be careful, it returns DWORD, but inside there are two SHORTS (16-bit signed ints) packed. So LOWORD/HIWORD macros (or C# respective) won't work.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644938(VS.85).aspx